# How to use java runtime 11 in EMR cluster AWS

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-emr, java-11

I'm creating a cluter in EMR aws and when spark runs my application I'm getting error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
com/example/demodriver/MyClassFromJAR has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), 
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I'm using releaseLabel `emr-6.5.0` on clusters and My driver jar is built in java11

How run java11 application in EMR? Or this error is about anything else?

Comment: Hi this means that your code was compiled on your machine with version 55 (Could be Java 11). But that the machine where you run the code is a lower version, so that won't work. Update the target machine to the same version.

Comment: Yeh, I think this is the reason, but I don't know how to configure EMR java runtime. Does EMR suport java 11 and how to set up this?

Comment: Try this

https://omkarkulkarni.medium.com/quick-guide-to-bootstrapping-java-11-on-emr-d70f0115efe8

Comment: This is really good :) I'll try it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the most recent versions of EMR, java 11 is installed.  To enable it, you can provide the following [configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html).

```json
[
    {
        "Classification": "spark-env",
        "Configurations": [
            {
                "Classification": "export",
                "Properties": {
                    "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Classification": "spark-defaults",
        "Properties": {
            "spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64"
        }
    }
]
```

This does not seem to be documented.

The `defaultJavaOptions` and `extraJavaOptions` might contain incompatible options for java 11 which you still might need to adapt/update.

**update:**

From EMR 6.12.0 onward there is [official support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/configuring-java8.html) for multiple jvms, using the methods specified above.

Comment: I confirm this works.

Comment: I'd think one has to be careful if the EMR cluster is configured to use instance types that are not x86_64, like the Graviton instances, or mixed instance fleets.

Comment: @Steven, where do you add this configuration? I am creating a Serverless EMR job and have an application running with Spark 3.2. I want to submit a job in this application that runs Java 11. Does it go in the job configuration block?

Comment: @manishbelsare correct: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html

Comment: I just had a discussion with a guy in the AWS support, they say that the usage of Java 11 on EMR is still discouraged. And also that this is the right way of doing it (it could be `.aarch64` depending on the hardware)

Comment: @MauroPiccotti I guess you have to try it out.  For our workflow java 11 gives significant better results in  recent spark versions.  And for java 17, after `yum install java-17-amazon-corretto-headless`, it is even significantly better.
But your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full configuration including the necessary JVM options:

```json
[
    {
        "Classification": "spark-env",
        "Configurations": [
            {
                "Classification": "export",
                "Properties": {
                    "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Classification": "spark-defaults",
        "Properties": {
            "spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64",
            "spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions": "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70",
            "spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions": "-verbose:gc -Xlog:gc*::time -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

For running Spark (3.3.0) on EMR 6 (6.9.0) I had to provide the following (note the additional "hadoop-env" and the empty "Properties" elements):

```
[
{
    "Classification": "hadoop-env", 
    "Configurations": [
        {
            "Classification": "export", 
            "Configurations": [], 
            "Properties": {
                "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64"
            }
        }
    ], 
    "Properties": {}
}, 
{
    "Classification": "spark-env",
    "Configurations": [
        {
            "Classification": "export",
             "Configurations": [],
            "Properties": {
                "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Properties": {}
},
{
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
        "spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64"
    }
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

In EMR 6.10.0, Java 11 is pre-installed. To utilize it in applications, we can simply add a bootstrap action to update the alternative:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin/java
```

With this, Java 11 will be set as default runtime in EMR nodes. Note that Java 11 doesn't recognize some options from previous runtime version, so the application or service may fail to start. For Spark, if the containers fail to start JVM, consider passing configuration "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions". Similarly, other service like Hive-hcatalog-server can also fail to start, which can be addressed as below:

```
[
    {
        "classification": "spark-defaults",
        "properties": {
            "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions",
            "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"
        }
    },
  {
    "Classification": "hcatalog-env",
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
          "HADOOP_OPTS": "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {}
  }
]
```

Hope that helps!