# Set Java version 11 in transient EMR Cluster for Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm creating transient EMR cluster using following lambda code :

```
   List<Configuration> configurations = new ArrayList<>();
            configurations.add(new Configuration()
                .withClassification("emrfs-site")
                .withProperties(Collections.singletonMap("fs.s3.consistent.retryPolicyType", "fixed")));

            configurations.add(new Configuration()
                .withClassification("spark")
                .withProperties(Collections.singletonMap("maximizeResourceAllocation", "true")));

            Map<String,String> config = new HashMap<>();
            config.put("JAVA_HOME", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64");
            config.put("spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions", "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70");
            config.put("spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions", "-verbose:gc -Xlog:gc*::time -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions");


            configurations.add(new Configuration()
                .withClassification("spark-env")
                .withConfigurations(Collections.singletonList(
                    new Configuration()
                        .withClassification("export")
                        .withProperties(Collections.singletonMap("JAVA_HOME","/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64"))
                )));

            configurations.add(new Configuration()
                .withClassification("spark-defaults")
                .withProperties(config));

            //collect customer IDs
            String customerIds = input.getCustomerIds();
            if (customerIds == null || customerIds.trim().equals("")) {
                  Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
                  final AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();
                  Map<String, AttributeValue> lastKeyEvaluated = null;
                  do {
                        ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
                            .withTableName(tableName)
                            .withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeyEvaluated);
                        ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
                        for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()) {
                              results.add(item.get(PARTITION_KEY).getS());
                        }
                        lastKeyEvaluated = result.getLastEvaluatedKey();
                  } while (lastKeyEvaluated != null);
                  customerIds = String.join(",", results);
            }

            //send to EMR cluster
            List<String> sparkSubmitArgs = new ArrayList<>();
            sparkSubmitArgs.add("spark-submit");
            sparkSubmitArgs.add("--master");
            sparkSubmitArgs.add("yarn");
            sparkSubmitArgs.add("--deploy-mode");
            sparkSubmitArgs.add("cluster");
            sparkSubmitArgs.add("--class");
            sparkSubmitArgs.add("spark.sparkjob.CreateSitemapFile");
            sparkSubmitArgs.add(backendCode);
            sparkSubmitArgs.add(customerIds);
            sparkSubmitArgs.add(s3FinalOutput);
            sparkSubmitArgs.add(s3SparkIntermediate);
            sparkSubmitArgs.add(tableName);
            AmazonElasticMapReduce emr = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.defaultClient();
            emr.runJobFlow(
                new RunJobFlowRequest()
                    .withName("sitemap_xml_generation")
                    .withInstances(
                        new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                            .withInstanceGroups(
                                new InstanceGroupConfig()
                                    .withName("Master")
                                    .withMarket(MarketType.ON_DEMAND)
                                    .withInstanceRole(InstanceRoleType.MASTER)
                                    .withInstanceType("m3.xlarge")
                                    .withInstanceCount(1),
                                new InstanceGroupConfig()
                                    .withName("Slave")
                                    .withMarket(MarketType.ON_DEMAND)
                                    .withInstanceRole(InstanceRoleType.CORE)
                                    .withInstanceType("m3.xlarge")
                                    .withInstanceCount(3)
                            )
                            .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
                            .withTerminationProtected(false)
                            .withEc2SubnetId(subnetId)

                    )
                    .withLogUri(emrLogUri)
                    .withReleaseLabel(EMR_VERSION)
                    //.withBootstrapActions(bootstrapActions)
                    .withSteps(
                        new StepConfig()
                            .withName("processFile")
                            .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.CONTINUE)
                            .withHadoopJarStep(
                                new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                                    .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                                    .withArgs(sparkSubmitArgs)
                            )
                    )
                    .withVisibleToAllUsers(true)
                    .withJobFlowRole(emrJobFlowRole)
                    .withServiceRole(emrServiceRole)
                    .withApplications(
                        new Application()
                            .withName("Spark"),
                        new Application()
                            .withName("Hive")
                    )
                    .withConfigurations(configurations)
            );
```

I've tried to follow instruction I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886684/how-to-use-java-runtime-11-in-emr-cluster-aws) in order to run java 11 code for Spark, but I'm still facing error : `"Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.